# Play sound from sdcard with MediaPlayer on android 2.3

Tags: android

This works with android 4.2:

```
SOUNDS_DIR = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
SoundToPlay = new MediaPlayer();
SoundToPlay.setDataSource(SOUNDS_DIR + ResourceID
        + ".mp3");
SoundToPlay.prepare();
SoundToPlay.start();
```

When i run it on android 2.3, LogCat prints:

> MediaPlayer error(1, -2147483648)

If i use the exactly same file as resource (/res/raw/), works fine also with 2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try before to validate your path, like:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
 File file = new File(path, ResourceID+".mp3");

 // if file exists ....
```

After you can write:

```
SoundToPlay = new MediaPlayer();
SoundToPlay.setDataSource(path + "/" + ResourceID  + ".mp3");
SoundToPlay.prepare();
SoundToPlay.start();
```

**[EDIT]**

Instead of

`SoundToPlay.setDataSource(SOUNDS_DIR + ResourceID
        + ".mp3");`

set

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(SOUNDS_DIR + ResourceID
    + ".mp3");
SoundToPlay.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());         
SoundToPlay.prepare();
```

Comment: Unfortunately i need to store my .mp3 files as private.  I also tried SoundToPlay.setDataSource(new File(SOUNDS_DIR + "/" + ResourceID
      + ".mp3").getAbsolutePath());

Comment: I think because `i need to store my .mp3 files as private.` let me know if its work, I forgot that Android from known External storage does that automatically

Comment: sure you are, after `prepare`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sound.mp3";
File file = new File(path);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);

if (mp != null)
{
   mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
         mp.release();
      }
   });
   mp.start();
}
```

Good Luck.

Comment: edited code from MediaPlayer.create(c, uri); to MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);

Comment: MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.fromFile(new File(SOUNDS_DIR + "/" + ResourceID + ".mp3")))
generates error(1, -25...

Comment: what is SOUNDS_DIR = ?

Comment: I test it. it works. what is the value of SOUNDS_DIR. post line of code.